# WPF form in a console app

Tags: c#, wpf, reflection

Im running a console app that loads a dll and calls a method from that dll that creates a WPF form. So I'm just calling to Program.Execute() method and it does all the creation of the form. All reflection business goes well, but the form does not appear.

[I've been told](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3843420/failed-to-create-a-window-when-launching-it-through-reflection-from-the-console-a) that this is because a console app does not have a windows message loop, but I'm sure there is a way to simulate that. For example, I tried playing with **System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame**, but to no avail - the form still does not show up.

Did anyone else face this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call WPF's Application.Run().  Or Window.ShowDialog(), same thing.  You will also have to apply the [STAThread] attribute on your Main() method.